# Can Illustrator convert jpg (rgb) image to cmyk when saving PDF file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, cmyk

Can Illustrator convert jpg (rgb) image to cmyk when saving PDF file?

Indesign can. Just wondering if this works also for Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When saving a PDF, see the 'Color Conversion' options under the 'Output' tab.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you do not "save" to a PDF, you export to PDF.

PDF does not come in one flavor, it can and needs to be configured in several ways. These configurations are saved as a PDF profile.

The main options you need to take into account are:

1. RGB -> CMYK and PMS ->CMYK or export the native format (RGB will stay as RGB and PMS as such)
2. Save the color profile used in this conversion.
3. Resample images beyond a specific PPI resolution.
4. Method of compression of these images.
5. Flatten transparency and effects.
6. Embed fonts or convert them to shapes.

---

For your specific case, it is better to use a predefined profile, more specifically a PDF/X-1a 2003. This will give you a good set of combinations for this export. If you navigate thru the settings you can see what is in this configuration.

---

This PDF is NOT a saved file, it is a different file, an output file. Always save your work in the native format of the application, in this case AI.